# Creating a TreeSet with a non-Comparable class: why a run-time exception, rather than compile-time error?

Tags: java, generics, treeset

If I create an arbitrary class that does not implement Comparable, and try to use it as a treeset, it throws an exception at run time when an object is inserted:

```
public class Foo {
}

public TreeSet<Foo> fooSet = new TreeSet<Foo>();
fooSet.add(new Foo()); // Throws a ClassCastException exception here: Foo is not comparable
```

I'm no Java expert, but something about this seemed dynamically typed (ala Python) in a way I wasn't expecting.  Is there no way for TreeSet's implementation to specify that its generic type argument must implement Comparable so that this can be caught at compile-time?  Non-generic functions can take interfaces as arguments; is the same not possible with generics?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`TreeSet` is implemented that way because you can [alternatively provide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet-java.util.Comparator-) a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), in which case the elements don't need to be [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). The only way to support both behaviors without splitting the implementation into multiple classes was to include runtime checks - this was simply a design decision by the author(s) of that class.

Exposing factory methods for `TreeSet` instead of public constructors would've been a way to maintain compile time checks using stricter generic type constraints, but that would've been a break from the core collections API's convention of exposing public no-arg and copy constructors for its implementation classes. As you noted in your comment, [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) goes the factory route with its collections and IMHO is better off for it.

Comment: Thank you - this makes perfect sense.  In fact, I note that Google's Guava library has a [TreeMultiSet](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultiset.html#create(java.util.Comparator)) class which is designed just as you describe - with two factories, one of which requires the generic extend Comparable, and one of which takes an appropriately typed Comparator.  I guess they decided to fix the design "bug" to bring more checks out to compile time.

Comment: Yeah, it's especially troublesome that `TreeSet` can't fail until you actually `put` an element that doesn't work, thanks to type erasure. Luckily it's at least a "fool me once" kind of failure, but still annoying not to catch it at compile time.

Comment: I think it's actually worse -- if I had a bunch of subclasses of `Foo`, and only some of them implemented Comparable, `add` won't throw an exception until one of the non-Comparables is finally inserted.  Who knows when that will finally happen?  This is a frustrating design choice: I use Java over dynamically typed languages partly to get away from the chaos of not having type checking until every code path has executed!

Comment: But why does the *Collection.sort(list)* method has such a compile time check? For the single argument function, compiler shows error when my class is not implementing *Comparable*.

Comment: @SreehariS Because that method is specific to elements that are Comparable, rather than being in a dual-role like `TreeSet` (Comparable elements, or has-Comparator).

Comment: @PaulBellora For *Collections.sort()* also, it can have a dual role as in *public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)* , right?

Comment: @SreehariS That's a separate method that declares different type constraints. `TreeSet` is a single type that must declare one set of type constraints for both scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a type-safe wrapper for TreeSet:

```
public class TypeSafeTreeSet<T extends Comparable<? super T>> extends TreeSet<T> {
}
```