# Why Java PriorityQueue<T> does not enforce a Comparable Object

Tags: java, generics, collections, priority-queue

Why is PriorityQueue in Java defined as,

`PriorityQueue<T>`

and not as,

`PriorityQueue<T extends Comparable<? super T>`

It rather gives a ClassCastException at runtime if do not queue objects of type Comparable. (and if I am not using a custom Comparator).

Why not catch it at compile time?

Comment: related: [Creating a TreeSet with a non-Comparable class: why a run-time exception, rather than compile-time error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13890542/creating-a-treeset-with-a-non-comparable-class-why-a-run-time-exception-rather)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's done so that you can still use the priority queue for Objects that do not implement the `Comparable` interface. In such cases you just supply your own custom comparator and everything just works.

This increases the usability of the class, at minimal to no cost. This behavior is well-documented in the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html).