# What are the benefits of throwing runtime exceptions over compile time checks for collections that enforce comparable types?

Tags: java, data-structures, comparable

When implementing my own data structures which require a comparable type I've always done so like this:

`public class ComparableCollection<E extends Comparable<E>> { ... }`

This obviously enforces the comparable constraint at compile time. But I've been a student for the last couple years and have somehow overlooked the fact that the Java implementations for collections that enforce a comparable type do not do so at compile time but rather at runtime by possibly throwing a `ClassCastException` while adding an element; e.g.:

`public class TreeSet<E> extends AbstractSet<E>
    implements NavigableSet<E>, ... { ... }`

`TreeSet` is backed by a `NavigableMap` which, if it's `Comparator` is `null`, attempts to cast the key like so:

`Comparable<? super K> k = (Comparable<? super K>) key;`

Now, if the type being inserted isn't comparable a `ClassCastException` is thrown.

What are the real benefits of this design over enforcing the constraint at compile time?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13890542/creating-a-treeset-with-a-non-comparable-class-why-a-run-time-exception-rather. Elements in a `TreeSet` do not need to be comparable, you can give explicitely a comparator.

Comment: @Tunaki, amazing how something makes a lot more sense when you get out of your own head. That just makes way too much sense. Having a duh moment now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The benefit is that you can then use TreeSet with objects that do not implement `Comparable` but for which you can provide a `Comparator`.

For more about the differences between Comparable an Comparator, see: [Java : Comparable vs Comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108604/java-comparable-vs-comparator)

Comment: Some further explanation, please?

Comment: Indeed. Just because a class does not implement `Comparable` doesn't mean it wouldn't need to be or isn't comparable.

Answer (score 0):

You can not control what objects are getting inserted in Collection at Compile time always. Its more flexible to allow dynamic definition of the Collection.