# Can natural ordering be enforced via Java generic type system?

Tags: java, generics, types

[TreeSet(Collection<? extends E> c)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet(java.util.Collection)) constructor was defined as:

> Constructs a new tree set containing the elements in the specified collection, sorted according to the **natural ordering** of its elements. All elements inserted into the set **must implement the Comparable interface**. Furthermore, all such elements must be mutually comparable: e1.compareTo(e2) must not throw a ClassCastException for any elements e1 and e2 in the set.

Is it possible syntactically enforce that `E` in `Collection<? extends E>` implements `Comparable`? In above JavaDoc this check postponed to execution time...

Comment: They could have done `class TreeSet<E extends Comparable<? super E>>`, but then you wouldn't have been able to use custom comparators for unorderable types.  I can't think of a good way to enforce this only on a single constructor.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13890542/creating-a-treeset-with-a-non-comparable-class-why-a-run-time-exception-rather

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537500/java-the-meaning-of-t-extends-comparablet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but not with constructors; you'd have to expose a factory method, which can impose constraints on the collection type beyond those imposed by the class as a whole.  For example, they could've written

```
public class TreeSet<E> { ...
  public static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> TreeSet<E>
      create(Collection<? extends E> collection) {
    TreeSet<E> set = new TreeSet<E>();
    set.addAll(collection);
    return set;
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: That is because with factory you are not restricted declaring placeholder type ``E``  on ``class`` level?

Comment: Er, the class as a whole can declare restrictions, and methods can, but individual constructors can't.

Comment: No, static has nothing to do with this.

Comment: That is, methods can declare constraints on their own type parameters but not the type parameter of the class it's called on (if it's not static).  But in a factory method, you're using a type parameter of the method and making it the type parameter of the *returned* class does the job.

Comment: This may be a good time to point out that there are separate formal type parameters present in your example (with the same name).  The `E` in `public class TreeSet<E>` is not the `E` in `public static <E extends ...>`.  It is my preference to avoid reusing the class formal type parameter symbol in generic static methods to make this distinction clear and to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your project require this by using a factory method like this:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> SortedSet<T> safeSortedSet() {
    return new TreeSet<T>();
}
```

Then is code:

```
Set<String> pass = safeSortedSet();
Set<Foo> fail = safeSortedSet();
```

Second line produces compile error:

> Error:(99, 38) java: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
>       equality constraints: Test.Foo
>       upper bounds: java.lang.Comparable

Answer (score 0):

From **Tavian Barnes** comment:

> They could have done class `TreeSet<E extends Comparable<? super E>>`, but then you wouldn't have been able to use custom comparators for unorderable types. I can't think of a good way to enforce this only on a single constructor

So it is possible with `<E extends Comparable<? super E>>` syntax, but unfortunately each generic `extends` / `super` syntax make ultimate restriction on any other type declaration with `E`.

In case TreeSet look to [Creating a TreeSet with a non-Comparable class: why a run-time exception, rather than compile-time error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13890542/creating-a-treeset-with-a-non-comparable-class-why-a-run-time-exception-rather)

Thanks for all who helps with answer!