# Collections.sort() shows error in compile time while add() method in TreeSet shows at runtime

Tags: java, collections, tree, set, comparable

I have a class `Student` which **does not** implement `Comparable`.

Case 1: I created a `TreeSet`of `Student` objects. `mySet.add(s1)` does not throw error at compile time, but throws error at runtime. (I could find explanations for this eg: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13890542/creating-a-treeset-with-a-non-comparable-class-why-a-run-time-exception-rather))

```
Student s1= new Student(12,"ABCD");
Student s2= new Student(2,"EFGH");
Set<Student> mySet=new TreeSet<Student>();
mySet.add(s1);//shows error only at run time
```

Case 2:
 I created an `ArrayList` of `Student` objects and tried to sort using `Collections.sort(myList)`. Now, this shows an error at compile time itself.

```
Student s1= new Student(12,"ABCD");
Student s2= new Student(2,"EFGH");
List<Student> myList=new ArrayList<Student>();
myList.add(s1);
myList.add(s2);
Collections.sort(myList); //shows error in the IDE
```

Why is there a difference in the two cases?

Comment: And the errors are?

Comment: case 1: java.lang.ClassCastException: Student cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable (Runtime)
case 2 :  The method sort(List<T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (Set<Student>)

Comment: Is it not that `Collections.sort()` applies only to `List`?

Comment: list also shows the same error

Answer (score 2):

That's because `TreeSet` needs to conform to the specifications of `Set` (which allows non-Comparable elements), whereas `Collections.sort()` doesn't and can use `Comparable` in the signature to make sure it's being caught at compile time.

Comment: 'TreeSet<Student> mySet=new TreeSet<Student>();' . Why can't TreeSet add more constraints on top of what it inherited from 'Set'? (Sorry if the question is silly)

Answer (score 2):

> Why is there a difference in the two cases?

Because these are distinct methods of different classes : `java.util.Collections.sort()` and `java.util.Set.add()`.

`Collections.sort()` expects a `List` of `Comparable` :

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list) {
    list.sort(null);
}
```

Whereas the compilation error as you don't pass a `List` but a `Set`. Besides even if you passed a `List` it would not work as `Student` is not a `Comparable`

While `TreeSet` implements the `Collection.add()` method that accepts any type matching to the generic of the collection :

```
public class TreeSet<E> ... {
    ...
    public boolean add(E e) {
            return m.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
    }
    ...
}
```

Passing a `Student` to `add()` being valid for a `Set<Student>` declared variable, so the compilation passes.

Comment: Couldn't it have been better if there is a check for 'Comparable' in the add(E e) method of TreeSet you pasted above?

Answer (score 1):

```
Set<Student> mySet = new TreeSet<Student>();
mySet.add(s1);//shows error only at run time
```

mySet is a Set and could be a HashSet: `Set.add` cannot require that the added element is a Comparable. As `add` on a HashSet could go by Object.hashCode. The compiler does not do an analysis that the actual Set is a TreeSet.

One could do:

```
SortedSet<Student> mySet
```

And as said by others `Collections.sort` requires the elements to be comparable to be sortable.